# How many memory an Excel XLL plugin can have?

Tags: c++, excel, memory, xll, xlw

I'm using C++ to write a .XLL plugin for Microsoft Excel, with the help of [XLW library](http://xlw.sourceforge.net/). My operating system is windows 7 64-bit version, with 32 GB RAM; but my Excel is Excel 2010, 32-bits version.

Checking with [GlobalMemoryStatusEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366589.aspx), it shows that the code in XLL can only see about 1200 MB virtual memory available (from `ullAvailVirtual` in [struct _MEMORYSTATUSEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366770.aspx)), though the physical memory available (`ullAvailPhys`) is around 23 GB.

As my code requires quite a lot memory (about 100MB per computation thread), after issuing 12 threads it hits the bad allocation error.

Is there a way to increase the memory available?

1. Is this a limitation of Excel `XLL` plugin? In a Console Application, `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` reports around 2034 MB Virtual Memory available.
2. Is this a limitation of `XLW library`?
3. Is this a limitation of `32-bit Excel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XLL is actually just a renamed DLL.  If you have a 32-bit Excel, then the whole Excel process has a 32-bit virtual address space to live in (and Windows reserves half of that for the OS).  So your process (both XLL and Excel itself), is limited to a total of 2G.

Your choices are:

1. Switch to a 64-bit Excel (which implies that your XLL will need to be 64-bit)
2. Let the XLL remain 32-bit, and make it launch a separate (possibly 64-bit) process, and do the processing in that.

The latter option is obviously much more complicated, and copying data between processes will not be that snappy - but it *is* an option.

Comment: Do you mean that, my `A.XLL` is still a 32-bit DLL, but it lanches a separate (possibly 64-bit) process `B.exe`, and have the `32-bit Excel` - `32-bit A.XLL` - `64-bit B.exe` communication?

Comment: @athos: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: If so, how could `A.XLL` talks with `B.exe` efficiently? The speed is my concern.

Comment: Probably the fastest way is going to be memory mapped files for bulk data transfer.  You might want to use some other mechanism for notifications (Windows messages, TCP IP, Windows Events, etc).